# typescript type object with string keys and content defined by interface

Tags: typescript

my data has this structure:

```
groups = {
    someGroupName: {
        total: 30,
        count: 3,
        average: 10
    },
    someOtherGroupName: {
        total: 60,
        count: 3,
        average: 20
    }
}
```

I can write an interface for the nested part:

```
interface Stats {
    total: number,
    count: number,
    average: number
}
```

but how can I set a type for groups as a whole? I do not know what groups are coming in. I just know that it will be a groupname as the key and the stats object as the value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use an index signature to tell typescript that the object is indexable by any string but all values in the object are of a certain type:

```
interface Stats {
    total: number,
    count: number,
    average: number
}

interface Groups {
    [name: string] : Stats
}

let groups: Groups = {
    someGroupName: {
        total: 30,
        count: 3,
        average: 10
    },
    someOtherGroupName: {
        total: 60,
        count: 3,
        average: 20
    }
}

let someGroupName = groups['someGroupName'] //someGroup is Stats
groups['someGroupName'] = 0 // invalid 0 is not of type Stats
```

Comment: Could you use a `Record<string, Stats>` as opposed to the Groups Interface?

Answer (score 15):

## Simpler way

You can use `{[key:string]:string}` as a type for any object with string values and string keys.

```
type strObj = {[key:string]:string}

const sample:strObj = {
    one:"text1",
    two:"text2"
}
```

**For nested Object**

And if it is a nested object, you can nest the type in place of the second `string` at the end.

`{[key:string]:` **`string`**`}` ==> `{[key:string]: {[key:string]:string}}`

Hence,

```
type strObj = {[key:string]:{[key:string]:string}}
const sample:strObj = {
    one:{
        sub:"text1"
    },
    two:{
        sub:"text2"
    }
}
```