# Defining a complex object in Typescript with text key values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a set of search options in a React component. I am keeping track of the values of these options in a State. The options are of a couple of different types, and thus this object is different kinds of values in its interface. When I try to access any of the properties in the options object, I am getting an error that says that I can't use a string to identify these properties: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'searchOptions'.`

So here is my interface:

```
interface searchOptions { 
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: boolean;
  prop4: boolean;
  prop5: boolean;
}
```

and here is my initial useState declaration:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({
  prop1: 0,
  prop2: 0,
  prop3: false,
  prop4: false,
  prop5: false
} as searchOptions);
```

and for each of my form elements, I have an onChange that refers to this handler:

```
const handleOption = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { id, value } = e.target;
  console.log(options[id]);
};
```

At the moment, all I'm trying to do is confirm I can access the appropriate option. I'll do more later, but right now I'm just doing the "am I getting it right so far"?

But this is where I get my compile error. `e.id` is a string, and when I try to access `options[id]` is where I get the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'searchOptions'`.

I tried the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973228/typescript-type-object-with-string-keys-and-content-defined-by-interface), changing my current interface to a type and nesting it inside a larger object interface, but that yielded a different compile error. Could I get some guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

...aaaaaaand of course I had thought about it too hard. I needed to loosen up the rules of the interface:

```
interface searchOptions {
  [key: string]: number | boolean;
}
```

Et voila.

Comment: This approach is extremely permissive and I wouldn't recommend it. It also does not give you very useful type hinting for `searchOptions` at all and can easily lead to bugs. An alternative approach would be to simply cast your `id` value when you use it, which preserves the usefulness of `searchOptions` and limits the impact of casting operators. e.g. `options[id as keyof searchOptions]`

Comment: @jered, thank you that worked splendidly!